# Is the Javascript variable declaration shorthand making variables global or local?

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, shorthand

I understand that the variables in the following function will only be available in this function;

```
function(){
    var x;
    var y;
    var z = 3;
});
```

But I don't know about the following in shorthand. What is their scope? **(Y and Z)**

```
function(){
    var x, y, z=3;
});
```

And If there's something I can go read somewhere about this shorthand please provide a link.

Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK both declarations are essentially the same.

Comment: If you write like `var a=b=c=3`, here b and c are global variable.

Comment: Here is some useful information on 'var' : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both represent exactly the same thing, and thus the variables carry same scope. They will be defined everywhere inside this function.

You can read more about it [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#Declaring_and_initializing_two_variables).

Answer (score 0):

The variables declared without var keyword are made global variable.

Don't know the reason behind this. But I have tested this.

Also, in your 2nd example as well, the variables will be local to that function only as you have used var for 1st variable and it is continued by using comma.

Try this example

```
var a=10:
Function test()
{c=11; var b=12; a=0;}

    console.log(a);
    test();
    console.log(a);
    console.log(b);
    console.log(c);
```

Comment: What is the purpose of using jquery (?) in your example?

Comment: Was simply writing a function to run onload. That could be replaced. I will do that. Thanks :)

Comment: Why do you even want to run something on-load? Why not just put those `console.log` right after without any on-load stuff?

Comment: Agreed. Removed it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In javascripts,
If you assign a value to a variable that has not been declared, it will automatically become a GLOBAL variable.

In your case you are declaring then assigning value (var x,y,z = 3).

They all will be in local scope only.

For learning more about scope you can go through [W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp).